# Windows Service opening a mail box

Tags: .net, mapi

WE had exchange server 2007  mail box.There is windows service which uses MAPI protocol to pull the mails from mailbox.

The mailbox is migrated to exchange server 2013.The windows service started reporting issues like Mapi logon failed.

On checking with messaging team ,they have told that MAPI is no longer supported in exchange server 2013.

It would great if you can advise,if you have faced the problem earlier .

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not here for server tech support.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! From the tone of your question, it sounds like you may be a sysadmin venturing into the programming world. If so, you may want to pass the issue onto a developer. If, on the other, you're a capable programmer, then cheers, and good luck going forward with a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to switch to using either IMAP or EWS to talk to your exchange box.

Also, I [found this snippet](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2013/02/01/exchange-server-2013.aspx):

> All MAPI traffic is RPC-based. Historically, Outlook clients have had
>   two transport methods for RPC traffic available to them: RPC over TCP,
>   and RPC over HTTP (aka Outlook Anywhere). In Exchange 2013, we removed
>   the RPC over TCP option, leaving RPC over HTTP as the only
>   connectivity method. This does not mean RPC is no longer supported. In
>   fact, it is still used (e.g., we still make MAPI/RPC calls), we just
>   encapsulate them in HTTP packets.

So, it stands to reason that your old MAPI-based code could still work if made to use HTTP. Not sure what that would entail, but if it saves you the trouble of converting to a different protocol (read: server config instead of code changes), it could be worth the research time.

One last note: take a look at [this MSDN page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn635177%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) that discusses MAPI over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks.How can i make the old mapi code to use HTTP?Any help  or sample is appreciated

Comment: Also we donot open the mailbox using outlook we use the below code objExchServer = new MAPI.SessionClass();  objExchServer.Logon(null, null, false, true, true, true, strProfileInfo);

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2013 only supports ROH (RPC-over-HTTP) connections. You need to create a profile that uses ROH - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/16/create-outlook-profile-exchange-2013.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/16/create-outlook-profile-exchange-2013.aspx

Comment: Hi Dmitry,Thanks but this is to be done at server right

Comment: I am not sure I understand - it needs to be done wherever the code is running. Where did your old MAPI code run?

Comment: MY MAPI old code is running in windows server in form of windows service . We are using CD01.2.1 and session.MAPI.logon method .

Comment: objExchServer.Logon(null, null, false, true, true, true, strProfileInfo); strprofile info is exchangeserver\networkID.Is there any way so that i can set port number in the profile info so that i can specify to loginto the particular port of exchange server

Comment: So you are using CDO 1.21, not Extended MAPI, right? CDO 1.21 has not been updated (at least functionality-wise) for over 10 years, so it does not support dynamic ROH profiles. Your options are either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) and its RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox method (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm)

Comment: Thanks . I have checked this.Dont you think changing the protocol is risky and effort consuming :(.Entire code is wirtten with CDO 1.2.1.My problem seems ,my service is unable to connect to server because the server listens only to a particular port.If some way i can specify port number in profile info then i think it should resolve the issue

Comment: Even if i migrate to Reddemption still the issue of connecting to specific port remains. I am using c#

Comment: port 135 seems to be blocked for the OWA server

Comment: yes, it is risky and time consuming. But I don't think you have much of a choice - CDO 1.21 cannot create dynamic ROH profiles no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks.Seems i got stuck in serious issue ,Client is suggesting to use IMAP or Install outlook and retrieve the mail using interop.outlook.Can you suggest any suitable work around.I have asked to expose port 135 and let me check if it works.

Comment: What does this have to do with port 135? ROH uses the standard HTTP and HTTPS ports. Again, your code must be rewritten, there is no way around that.

Comment: MAPI used to connect via port 135 to  exchange server 2007 the exchange server 2013 MAPI is trying to connect via port 135 but that port is blocked .The error is MAPI_E_LOGON Failed

Comment: Exchange version of MAPI (or Outlook) might want to try to connect using the old RPC connection type, but Exchange 2013 only allows ROH connections.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,Can i use redemption to re write the code??

Comment: Yes, you can use RDOSession.LogonSharedExchangeMailbox (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm)

Comment: Where can i get the latest version of reedemption for c#?

Comment: You can download the latest dev version from http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm

Comment: Is it free can i use it in live producion project??

Comment: The free (dev) version displays an UELA dialog box every once in a while. The distributable version (necessary if you use Redemption for any business related purposes) displays no prompts.